# A set of 6 numbers

Tags: number-theory

Given 6 integers, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, and 6. Choose 2 numbers a and b. Rewrite a as 2a+b and b as 2b+a. (This move can be repeated)
I want to know which of the following sets of integers can be formed. 
(0, 0, 0, 3, -6, 9), (0, 1, 1, -3, 6,-6), (0, 0, 0, 3, -9, 9), (0,1,1,4,6,6)
Clearly the 1st and 4th set can be eliminated because regardless of which 2 numbers are chosen and rewritten, the set must still contain 3 evens and 3 odds. However the 2 sets remaining each has 3 evens and 3 odds. Furthermore, how do I identify, in general, without help of any computers, if a set of 6 numbers is constructible?

Comment: Presumably you are allowed to repeat this operation? Please make this clear if so.

Comment: The second set has four odds, not three.

Comment: Yes the operation is repeatable, and can be used on the same number multiples times.

Comment: And yes 2nd set has a typo

Comment: Please edit the typo !

Comment: Edited, sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: Note that

$$(2a+b)^2+(a+2b)^2=5a^2+8ab+5b^2\ge a^2+b^2$$

since $4a^2+8ab+4b^2=4(a+b)^2\ge0$.  Therefore each time you apply the move, the sum of the squares cannot decrease; it must, in fact, increase by a square multiple of $4$.  But

$$(-1)^2+2^2+(-3)^2+4^2+(-5)^2+6^2=91\gt83=0^2+1^2+1^2+(-3)^2+6^2+(-6)^2$$

This eliminates $(0,1,1,-3,6,-6)$.  The fourth set *can* be formed:

$$(-1,2,-3,4,-5,6)\to(-1,2,0,4,-5,9)\to(-1,2,0,3,-6,9)\to(-1,2,0,0,-9,9)\to(0,3,0,0,-9,9)$$

followed by reordering, or simply

$$(-1,2,-3,4,-5,6)\to(0,3,-3,4,-5,6)\to(0,3,-3,3,-6,6)\to(0,0,-3,3,-9,6)\to(0,0,0,3,-9,9)$$

without the need to reorder.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
This reasonning doesn't work now that the typo for $S_2$ has been corrected.
Actually my approach cannot bring anything since $f(S)$ will always be odd when S contains three odd and three even numbers...
I think I should leave the answer anyway as a draft because the key of this exercise must be to calculate some function of the set S that is invariant through the given transformation. The number of odd numbers being one, we ahve to find another to discriminate between $S_2$ and $S_3$.

Given a set $S=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, let $f(S)$ be the sum of the differences between two numbers of S, from right to left: $f(S)=(f-e)+(f-d)+...+(b-a)$ (15 terms)

When you transform S into S' by $a\leftarrow a+(a+b)$ and $b\leftarrow b+(a+b)$, the difference $(b-a)$ is unaffected and the 14 others change by $+/-(a+b)$, so the total change in $f(S)$ can be either $0 , 2(a+b), ..., 14(a+b)$ : it is necessary an even number.

Since your initial set $S_0$ has $f(S_0)=19$, only sets $S$ such as $f(S)$ is odd can be reached.

$S_2=\{0,1,1,-3,6,9\}$ has $f(S_2)=56$ (even), so it cannot be reached.

$S_3=\{0,0,0,3,-9,9\}$ has $f(S_2)=21$ (odd), so it may be reached.

By elimination, $S_3$ must be the right answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, however although this may help in competitions where there is definitely an answer, this doesn't suffice to prove that the 3rd set can definitely be formed.